# powershell script to show git info and just the working directory

Tags: powershell

I've done some googling and havent found a solution so I was hoping for some help here.

Ive installed posh-git to use with powershell and want to keep the git status it adds to the prompt line, but I dont want the entire working directory printed because its annoying. I just want the current folder. Ive found the code to do each, but have no idea how to combine them.

The default posh-git to print path and git info is

```
function global:prompt {
$realLASTEXITCODE = $LASTEXITCODE

# Reset color, which can be messed up by Enable-GitColors
$Host.UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor = $GitPromptSettings.DefaultForegroundColor

Write-Host($pwd.ProviderPath) -nonewline

Write-VcsStatus

$global:LASTEXITCODE = $realLASTEXITCODE
return "> "
}
```

the code to just print the current folder in the path is

```
function prompt { 
'PS ' + ($pwd -split '\\')[0]+' '+$(($pwd -split '\\')[-1] -join '\') + '> '
}
```

Ive tried various mishmashes of both and havent figured out how to make it do what I want.

heres a pic to help illustrate

[image]

any help would be great, thank you :)

Comment: Don't print `$pwd.ProviderPath` then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of printing `$pwd.ProviderPath`, print `Split-Path -Leaf`:

```
function global:prompt {
    $realLASTEXITCODE = $LASTEXITCODE

    # Reset color, which can be messed up by Enable-GitColors
    $Host.UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor = $GitPromptSettings.DefaultForegroundColor

    Write-Host(Split-Path -Leaf $pwd.ProviderPath) -nonewline

    Write-VcsStatus

    $global:LASTEXITCODE = $realLASTEXITCODE
    return "> "
}
```